# Bit Shifting in PowerShell 2.0

Tags: powershell, bit-manipulation, powershell-2.0, bit-shift

Shift left (`-shl`) and shift right (`-shr`) operators are only available with PowerShell 3.0 and higher.

How can I shift in PowerShell 2.0?

This is what I have so far. Is there a better way?

```
>>>$x = 1
>>>$shift = 3
>>>$x * [math]::pow(2, $shift)
8
>>>$x = 32
>>>$shift = -3
>>>$x * [math]::pow(2, $shift)
4
```

Comment: That depends what you mean by "better"

Comment: Cleaner, more efficient. `1 << 3` would be swell, but it is not possible.

Comment: I'd say the cleanest way is to upgrade PowerShell. All supported Windows versions can run at least PowerShell v3.

Comment: I still have to deal with Windows XP some.

Comment: Although not explicitly "supported", Windows Management Framework 3.0 will work on XP SP3 just fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't implement new operators in PowerShell (afaik), but you could wrap the operation inside a function:

```
function bitshift {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory,Position=0)]
        [int]$x,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Left')]
        [ValidateRange(0,[int]::MaxValue)]
        [int]$Left,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Right')]
        [ValidateRange(0,[int]::MaxValue)]
        [int]$Right
    ) 

    $shift = if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Left')
    { 
        $Left
    }
    else
    {
        -$Right
    }

    return [math]::Floor($x * [math]::Pow(2,$shift))
}
```

That makes use a little more readable:

```
PS> bitshift 32 -right 3
4
PS> bitshift 1 -left 3
8
```

Comment: This fails with arguments like `bitshift 0xFFFF -right 1`. It returns 32767.5 instead of 32767. Casting the return value to an [int] will fix that problem. If OP wants to use this with 64 bit numbers, precision loss will occur if the shift is 53 or more to the right. That can't easily be fixed with this approach, because [math]::pow only takes [double] arguments which have 52 bits of precision.

Comment: @user2460798 good catch, updated sample in answer (I've floor'd it instead, any decimal value are bits that should have been shifted away anyways)

Comment: Floor won't work if the number is negative: `bitshift -1 -right -1` gives -1. Results of Floor go towards negative infinity, whereas casting to [int] goes towards zero

Comment: Value `-1` is not a valid argument to `-Right`

Comment: Does the OP know that? Don't think he said to exclude negative numbers. Also same problem happens with `0xFFFFFFFF -right -1`

Comment: Again, look at the function, `-1` is not a valid argument. I'm not claiming to have re-implemented a fully functional bitwise operator - I'm simply showing OP how to wrap an operation he's already doing (and suggested himself) in a meaningful function

Comment: But 0xFFFFFFFF isn't inherently signed. It can represent 4G-1 or it can represent -1. Or it can be a bit mask, bit field, or a struct represented in 32 bits. Those are all legitimate operands of a right shift operation.

Comment: @user2460798 Absolutely correct, I'm not arguing with you. I'm just telling you, this answer is not (meant to be) a fully funtional bitshift operator. It's just a powershell function that performs a bitwise shift on a positive 32-bit signed integer, nothing more. Feel free to implement a more robust alternative that works on all numeric input types and post an answer as well, no one is stopping you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102171/discussion-between-user2460798-and-mathias-r-jessen).

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the same problem, and I'd like to include some useful information:

[PoSh2.0-BitShifting](https://github.com/coolmacool/PoSh2.0-BitShifting) creates a `$Global:Bitwise` object that provides most of the bitwise operations.

Example of use (from its own readme):

```
PS C:\> Enable-BitShift
PS C:\> $Bitwise

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PoShBitwiseBuilder                       System.Object


PS C:\> $Bitwise::Lsh(32,2)
128
PS C:\> $Bitwise::Rsh(128,2)
32
```